# PHP & MySQL - Populate Select Dropdown using Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to populate my dropdown using an array on another page so here is what I've got I need to populate my dropdown select a list of nationalities, so far I've got an array of list of nationalities but I cannot populate the select box on the array.

on my `fetch.php`

I've got

`<?php include('nationality.php') ?>`

```
<select id="register-nationality" name="registerNationality" required data-msg="Please select your Nationality" class="form-control">

                    <option>Select Nationality</option>

                    <?php 

                    foreach ($nationality as $national) {
                      echo "<option value='$nationals'>$nationals</option>";  
                    }

                     ?>

                  </select>
```

and in the `nationality.php` here is where I got the list of nationalities and it is an array.

so here is a sample of the code it is too long so I will give you the sample

```
    <?php 

$nationals = array(
        'Afghan',
        'Albanian',
        'Algerian',
        'American',
        'Andorran',
        'Angolan',
        'Antiguans',
        'Argentinean',
        'Armenian',
        'Australian',
        'Austrian',
        'Azerbaijani',
        'Bahamian',
        'Bahraini',
        'Bangladeshi',
        'Barbadian',
        'Barbudans',
..
..
..  and so on

);

 ?>
```

and so nothing is showing.

Comment: Yor foreach variable is `$nationals` and not `$nationality`. you have used `$nationals` which is not defined. your variable name is `$national`. in your loop change as `echo "<option value='$national'>$national</option>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your include statement to : `include_file "nationality.php";`

The name of your `array` is $nationals. You can't use `$nationality` because it doesn't exists.

Change your code to the following:

```
foreach($nationals as $national){
    echo "<option value='$national'>$national</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor foreach variable is `$nationals` and not `$nationality`. you have used `$nationals` which is not defined. your variable name is `$national`. in your loop change as `echo "<option value='$national'>$national</option>";`

```
$nationals = array(
    'Afghan',
    'Albanian',
    'Algerian',
    'American',
    'Andorran',
    'Angolan',
    'Antiguans',
    'Argentinean',
    'Armenian',
    'Australian',
    'Austrian',
    'Azerbaijani',
    'Bahamian',
    'Bahraini',
    'Bangladeshi',
    'Barbadian',
    'Barbudans',
);

foreach ($nationals as $national) {
  echo "<option value='$national'>$national</option>";  
}
```